# A very strange problem -> CSS file not detected .Java web application

Tags: java, css

If i browse my site using `http://localhost:8080/abc/Login/index.jsf`, everything works fine. But if browse it using simply `http://localhost:8080/abc`, the page is shown but all its images and css files are missing. What can be the problem?

I have this in my web.xml :-

```
 <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/Login/index.jsf</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/Login/index.jsf</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
```

Probably, images are not getting referenced correctly. Can anybody help me?

I have referenced css file as follows :-

```
<link href="./Css/MainStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

where Css is folder in Login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem (as you guessed) comes from how you have referenced the CSS.

Probably the easiest way to fix it is to be more specific with your reference:

```
<link href="/abc/Login/Css/MainStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This reference should work regardless of where the calling file is in your directory structure.